# Ec2 instance on AWS apt- get not working

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have Ec2 instance on AWS with Amazon Ubuntu.

When i try to download any thing, I am unable to do so.

For Ex:

```
~# apt-get update

0% [Connecting to ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (103.246.148.161)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.15)
```

Another Ex will be

```
~# wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip

--2014-04-09 07:27:17--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com... 207.171.189.80
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com|207.171.189.80|:443...
```

This remains forever.

I was able to download files until I created Group and user for AWS Console.

Please suggest what can be issues here.

Answer (score 58):

You EC2 instances's Security groups is not configured to let it reach internet. You need to have an `Outbound rule` for `all traffic` to `0.0.0.0/0`. In `EC2-Classic`, this is already in place and hence you need not worry. However, if this is in VPC, then you need to add this rule.

Also, Apart from what is said above, could you check whether any `iptables` rules causing any issue.

Comment: Also make sure you have assigned a public ip to the instance, I just wasted some time until I realized what the issue was.

Comment: @NikoNyrh, You do not need a public IP for this purpose. If that is how you got it working, then your doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Without a publicly accessible ip my EC2 instance couldn't even ping google.com or 8.8.8.8, maybe this only happens when being part of a company's VPC. I could SSH in by using the "internal" ip via VPN but couldn't connect out to open internet.

Comment: If you forgot you can go into the existing subnet and choose "automatically assign public IP"

Answer (score 5):

Also make sure that if you want to download anything using **wget** using HTTPS link .**Then add Outbound Rule for HTTPS ( Port 443 ) to 0.0.0.0/0**

Answer (score 1):

adding outbound rule HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0 work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue because I did not enable nat gateway for private subnet in vpc.

If your machine is in private subnet you'll have to enable nat gateway in route table for that subnet.

It ll look like this after enabled

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is not in your Security group, you might have forgotten to add the Ephemeral ports in the VPC/Subnet Network ACL.

In your route table, Allow inbound rule
`TCP` traffic from `32768 - 65535` on `0.0.0.0/0`

If you have only enabled 80, 443 in outbound, then the return traffic still comes through the temporary ports listed above. Only enabling 80, 443 outbound will not let your server complete a `curl google.com`

The ephemeral port list mentioned above is for ubuntu,
You can check yours by running
`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get apt-get to work again.

Edit gai.conf:

**sudo vim /etc/gai.conf**

change line ~54 to uncomment the following:

**precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100**

write and quit:

:wq

**CAUTION**

Look out line 50 which looks almost identical:

precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10

This is the wrong line. Go ~4 lines down and you'll find the correct line to uncomment because it ends with 100 instead of 10