# Stuck at Connecting to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com in amazon ec2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using amazon aws ec2 instance. I created an instance. I got a key-pair, and using that I logged in via ubuntu. Now, I am trying to run `sudo apt-get update` on the remote server. What I am getting is:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-46:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                   

Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease           

Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease         

Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                 
  Unable to connect to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 54.184.254.88 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 54.184.254.88 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 54.184.254.88 80]
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.15)]
```

I think that internet is not working on my server. After googling I got the following solution:
[Ec2 instance on AWS apt- get not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955682/ec2-instance-on-aws-apt-get-not-working), but it is already configured in my instance. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: How did you set up this EC2 instance internet access? in a VPC with an internet Gateway + public IP, in a VPC private subnet with NAT?

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to check your firewall settings. There is a probability you've set deny all outgoing connections.

```
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

This will allow connection to outside server