# Ubuntu 16 64bit - apt-get not working

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have fresh and clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.1 server edition. I have set static IP address. I can ping any domain. I can connect to it via SSH. Basically IP configuration is as it was on old Ubuntu 14. But apt-get doesn't work.

It's `0% [Connecting to gb.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::14)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::11)]`

I can ping domains it's trying to connect to `gb.archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com`.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955682/ec2-instance-on-aws-apt-get-not-working) is the most similar question I've found but this and answers to other questions doesn't resolve the issue.
I don't vahe any iptables rules as this is fresh and clean install.

After 5 hours spent on trying different solutions, different internet connections I'm running out of ideas.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a question for serverfault

Comment: Looks like it's trying to use IPv6. Check you can ping those domains with ping6

Comment: Thanks Rodney. I got ping: unknown host 2001:67c:1560:8001::14

Comment: try ping6, not ping.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rodney. Your comment directed me to find the solution. It's about IPv6. Just needed to disable it. Answer found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309461/how-to-disable-ipv6-permanently).

Comment: Disabling IPv6 is not a useful approach. Nor is disabling IPv4 when an IPv4 endpoint doesn't respond.

Why? Because the problem is on the remote side, not yours. Contact whoever owns that endpoint and ask them to fix it. In the meantime, TCP will eventually fail out addresses that don't respond, trying the others until it finds one that works.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This is my dev server run on VirtualBox so I don't need IPv6.

Comment: Just be sure to remember your debts! The day apt-get sees a DNS name with a AAAA but no A record, you'll have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I will.