# AWS Ubuntu AMI: sudo apt-get update halts at 0%

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have created an AWS AMI with Ubuntu Server 16.04 64 bit. After successfully logging into the server using SSH (`ssh -i keypair.pem ubuntu@x.x.x.x`, since it is a Ubuntu server) when I run `sudo apt-get update`, from command line, the process halts at:

> 0% [Connecting to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com (52.73.36.184)]
>   [Connecting to security.ubunErr:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>   xenial-security InRelease
>   Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80
>   (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP:
>   2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]

I have added my Public IP address to SSH, HTTP and HTTPS protocols under both Inbound and Outbound rules.

Am I missing something?

Comment: does your instance have an internet gateway?

Comment: I am new to AWS. Please let me know what does this mean.

Comment: Actually I could resolve the issue by adding All Traffic at 0.0.0.0/0 as Outbound rule. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955682/ec2-instance-on-aws-apt-get-not-working

Comment: Can you ping anything or use internet? Check using `ping google.com`.